# Как объединить значения в одной колонке в list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Допустим, имеется DataFrame:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |

Требуется преобразовать его к формату:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1, 2, 3] |
| 2 | [4, 5, 6] |

В принципе, преобразовать данные к такому виду можно перебором каждого `id`, вводя доп. переменную и создавая новый DataFrame.

Но мне интересно, есть ли решение данной задачи только средствами Pandas без ввода дополнительных переменных?

Comment: Научитесь задавать вопросы так, чтобы примеры, приведенные в них, были воспроизводимыми.

Comment: @strawdog, select dataset in browser -> press Ctrl+C -> `df = pd.read_clipboard()` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

группируем по `id` и применяем к группам `values` - `list`:

```
res = df.groupby("id")["value"].apply(list).reset_index()
```

результат:

```
In [433]: res
Out[433]: 
   id      value
0   1  [1, 2, 3]
1   2  [4, 5, 6]
```